# Batch file - pull commands from web resource

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I've tried several solutions to no avail, but am looking for a solution as to create a batch file that will run any commands located in a remote `.txt` file located on a website.

For example, somebody clicks on a `.bat` and the `.bat` retrieves a list of commands from `www.example.com/command.txt`, and then runs the contents of the `.txt` as if the commands were specified explicitly in the original `.bat` file. I am not opposed to using PowerShell or VBScript.

Comment: What are the solutions that have not availed? Also, the `.txt` file you've described is a batch file.

Comment: `wget` a website, make the result in variables, execute it.

Comment: wget or curl the website, in the batch a `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("X:\path\to\file.txt") Do %%A` should execute all the commands, but you see the danger trusting these commands not being malicious?

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell you can do this: `iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))`

i.e. this downloads and runs the PowerShell script: https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1

**Explanation**

- `New-Object System.Net.WebClient` creates a new instance of the .Net web client.
- `DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1')` invokes the web client's Download method to pull back the text from this script (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx).
- `iex` is an alias for `invoke-expression`.  This runs the downloaded string as if it were a command; i.e. causes PowerShell to execute the remote script.

**Simpler Version**

While the Chocolatey install script's an impressive 1 liner, the expanded version below may be simpler to understand (though ultimately does exactly the same as the above; just split over several lines).

```powershell
$scriptUri = 'https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'
$webClient = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Net.WebClient'
$scriptAsString = $webClient.DownloadString($scriptUri)
Invoke-Expression -Command $scriptAsString
```

---

The above example's taken from https://chocolatey.org/install